# Change the value of an integer in java

Tags: java, count, int, redefine

I'm starting out programming with java and I'd like to make some games and various other things which require *changing variables*, especially integers. Let me give you an example.

```
    int Score = 0;

    if(coinCollected = 1){
        int Score = 1
    }
```

Now of course this is going to return 'int Score has already been defined', or whatever, but I don't want it to say that, since I want to REdefine the variable. I've tried @Override before the if statement and that didn't work, either. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: If your intention is to change the value of `Score` already defined above the IF block, then just simply assign `1` to `Score` as `Score = 1`.

Comment: `coinCollected = 1` is a bug. For comparison you want to use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to update the value, if so, you don't need to re-define.

```
int Score = 0;

if(coinCollected == 1){
    // change the value
    Score = 1;
}
```

Comment: One more thing that you should keep in mind while programming in Java is to use variable names that start with lowercase letters. In your example you should have `int score`.

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to *redefine* the variable. You want to assign it a new value.

So simply remove the "int" from the second occurrence, so it looks like `score = 1`.

By the way, Java style conventions state variable names start with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

so you don't have to define Score again..
your code should look like this
    int Score = 0;

```
if(coinCollected == 1){
    Score = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(coinCollected = 1)
```

In the above statement you are assigning the value of 1 to variable named coinCollected, but thats NOT what you want to do, u want to compare the value 1 with the value of the variable named coinCollected.

**Eg:**

`if(coinCollected == 1)`

Now in the below code you are re-declaring the variable Score.

```
{

    int Score = 1
}
```

**Corrected code:**

```
int Score = 0;

if(coinCollected == 1){
     Score = 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a different scope, or reuse the existing `score` or preferably using a different name.

```
{
    int score = 0;

} // scope of Score has ended.

if(coinCollected == 1) {
    int score = 1;

}
```

Comment: Of course, that's assuming he actually wants a separate variable rather than changing the value stored in the existing one. Which I somehow don't consider likely.

Comment: That doesn't change the value of a variable though, it just declares another one.

Comment: The OP did say he wanted to *redefine* the variable.

Comment: The OP sounds a lot like he doesn't actually grasp the full extend of what that means. Which is no shame, and he wouldn't be the first beginner to misuse programming terminology. It's our job to figure that out and correct it :)

Comment: @Peter No, it's quite obvious he wants to change its value. It's keeping track of a _score_, why on Earth would he want to redefine it?

Comment: @AndresF. To keep the same name? If a variable represents a score, what else could you name it? Dinosaur?

Comment: @jsn Yes, of course there are all sorts of bizarre things one may want to do. But honestly, it's quite clear the poor guy is trying to update a score... let's not confuse him even more :)